# Dynamic left margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I set a dynamic left margin of a div depending on `$(window).width()`?

For example, for a width of `1886px` the margin should be `20%`, but for a width of `1280px` the margin should change to `10%`.

Comment: Whats the ratio here? Is it entirely arbitrary? I'd say look into `media queries` for this kind of behaviour.

Comment: you need to apply media queries for the resolutions you want to apply and write down the styles in it what what you want to apply for that resolutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

```
div {
     margin-left: 20%; /* Default */
}
@media (max-width: 1280px) { /* Apply these styles to 1280px width and under */
     div {
          margin-left: 10%;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS media queries is a way to go:

```
@media (max-width:1280px) {
    margin-left: 10%;
}
@media (min-width:1281px) {
    margin-left: 20%;
}
```